How to disable this spacing in svg viewbox?
.bullets {display: flex; align-items: flex-start; flex-direction: column; text-align: left; padding-inline-start: 4rem; list-style-type: none;
    > li {
        list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='25' height='15' xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox%3D%22-2 -2 28 21%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%3E.cls-1%7Bfill%3A%23000%3Bfont-family%3AInter-Medium%2C%20Inter%3Bfont-size%3A18px%3Bfont-variation-settings%3A%27wght%27%20500%2C%20%27slnt%27%200%3Bfont-weight%3A300%3Bletter-spacing%3A.02em%3B%7D%3C/style%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg id%3D%22PROJEKT%22%3E%3Ctext class%3D%22cls-1%22 transform%3D%22translate(0 15.54)%22%3E%3Ctspan x%3D%220%22 y%3D%220%22%3E%E2%9F%B6%3C/tspan%3E%3C/text%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    }
    &--check {
        > li {position: relative; padding-left: 1rem;
            list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='25' height='16' xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox%3D%22-2 -2 21 16%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%3E.cls-1%7Bfill%3A%234b91b8%3B%7D.cls-2%7Bfill%3Anone%3Bstroke%3A%23fff%3Bstroke-linecap%3Around%3Bstroke-linejoin%3Around%3B%7D%3C/style%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Ccircle class%3D%22cls-1%22 cx%3D%2210%22 cy%3D%2210%22 r%3D%2210%22/%3E%3Cpolyline class%3D%22cls-2%22 points%3D%224.5%2010%208.17%2013.67%2015.5%206.33%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
        }
    }
}

 <ul class="bullets">
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus imperdiet justo id turpis ultrices ullamcorper. Sed lobortis risus turpis, nec suscipit felis molestie porttitor. Nulla aliquam, lorem sed mattis rutrum, nisl orci vestibulum enim Sed imperdiet lectus libero, nec accumsan quam suscipit a. Pellentesque sed risus a ipsum auctor sodales sed in erat. Vivamus quis urna vel mauris hendrerit vehicula. Maecenas velit arcu, lobortis vitae risus vitae, feugiat laoreet ante.</li>
   <li>Proin eleifend convallis accumsan. Suspendisse vel congue lectus. Nulla et tortor a est convallis tempus vel sit amet libero. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Quisque efficitur ante et sapien efficitur varius. Fusce ac pulvinar dolor.</li>
   <li>Donec leo nulla, vulputate eu accumsan pulvinar, finibus accumsan metus. Etiam non nunc ac dolor convallis convallis. Pellentesque auctor tellus quam, dictum viverra mauris venenatis vel. Mauris vehicula fermentum interdum.</li>
</ul>


In li::marker there is a little hidden space under svg, li::marker has a height around 25px and width 25px. So why i cant resize svg in full box, in this case i can only use around 2/3 height. A little part of svg is hidden under nothing??? Please someone can help with that?

For the check mark you will need a different viewBox. Instead of viewBox%3D%22-2 -2 21 16 try viewBox%3D%22 0 0 20 20. Also I would remove the height or use the same value as the width,

I tried viewbox like this, but it doesnt work at all.

I solved that in different way, i changed li::marker to ::before and just added some padding, position: absolute on a before and left: 0, and it works.
